# Filtering a list of item components based on string property, without case-sensitivity

Tags: html, list, angular, typescript, pipe

I have this code, which generates item components, from my list of objects (Frivillig)

```
<app-frivillig-item
  *ngFor="let frivilligEl of frivillige"
  [frivillig]="frivilligEl">
</app-frivillig-item>
```

I now want to add a search field, which should dynamically change the list to whatever the user types. The list contains an array of objects, which each has several string properties. I only want to filter the list based on a single of these string properties. A property is a match if each character in the search text exists in the property at the same index (case-insensitive).

The list itself is located in a service, which is injected into the list component that instantiates the item components with *ngFor:

```
frivillige: Frivillig[]
```

This is my input field so far. It is currently 2-way bound to a string property in my list component:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" placeholder="Søg efter 
frivillig..." [(ngModel)]="term">
```

I am unsure how to approach this problem. I have tried using pipes, but found it confusing to implement, when the list is not just a set of strings. Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter in your component by maintaining a separate list of filtered items:

Template:

```
<app-frivillig-item
  *ngFor="let frivilligEl of filteredList"
  [frivillig]="frivilligEl">
</app-frivillig-item>

<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="term" (ngModelChange)="onChange()"/>
```

Component:

```
export class YourComponent {
  public term: string;

  // Initialize the filtered list to the complete list
  public filteredList = this.frivillige;

  public onChange() {
    // If nothing is in the search box, return to the complete list
    if (!this.term) {
      this.filteredList = this.frivillige;

      return;
    }

    // Filter the list for items that have the same characters at the same
    // indices as this.term (case-insensitive)
    this.filteredList = this.frivillige.filter(item => {
        return item.YOUR_PROPERTY.substring(0, this.term.length).toLowerCase() === this.term.toLowerCase();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i got it working! I will mark this answer as accepted. However i also want the user to be able to type just part of the string, and the list should filter itself based on that. For example, the user starts typing 'C' and all objects with the string property that has the first letter of 'C' will be returned.

Comment: Is it a match if the property contains the string anywhere? Or only at the beginning?

Comment: Only at the beginning. So far i made it work by comparing the first letter of the input and item string, after setting the input string to upper case. However this does not work when multiple items start with the same letter.

Comment: I'm not sure why it wouldn't work for multiple items. Can you show me the filter code?

Comment: this.filteredList = this.frivillige.filter(item => item.fornavn[0] === this.term[0]);
This code just checks whether the first input letter matches the first letter in any of the items. I assume i would need a loop to iterate through all letters to check for multiple items?

Comment: I think I still don't understand the requirement. What do you mean by "check for multiple items"? For each `fornavn` property string, do you want to see if any single letter in that string equals `this.term[0]`?

Comment: Sorry if i explained it poorly. I want the same functionality as displayed here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp
For each letter in the input string, it should check the letter in the same position in the 'fornavn' property string.

Comment: Oh, but that link isn't checking the positions. Type "d" and you will see "Adele". It's only checking to see if the string you typed is contained in one of the items. Which do you need?

Comment: Ah sorry, i missed that part. It should check from the first letter onwards, not just if the string is contained in the property. So far i made it check if the input letter at a certain position is at the same position in the property, disregarding the previous letters in the string:
    for (var index = 0; index < this.term.length; index++) {
      var element = this.term[index];
      this.filteredList = this.frivillige.filter(item => item.fornavn[index] === this.term[index]);
    }

Comment: I made it work now using the 'substr' method of string. However the search is still case-sensitive, which it should not be.
    for (var index = 0; index < this.term.length; index++) {
      var element = this.term[index];
      this.filteredList = this.frivillige.filter(item => item.fornavn.substr(0, this.term.length-1) === this.term.substr(0, this.term.length-1));
    }

Comment: You'd be overwriting `this.filteredList` in each inner loop. Check my update.

Comment: Thanks, your code works as well. I will try to make it non-case-sensitive.

Comment: I see now why you tried to use `substr`. If we remove the outer loop you have and make a couple of other small fixes, we have a cleaner solution. Check my update.